# XPath contains "\r\n" doesn't find any element on page

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is a page with some html:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div>
          text1 
    </div>
    <span>
        text2
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

And I want find element by text into the **li**.
If i'm trying to find it with xpath:

> "//*[contains(text(),'text1')]/ancestor::li"

- element founded and these text equal

> "text1\r\ntext2"

But if I'm trying find it like

> [contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]/ancestor::li"

There is no elements founded.
I tried use @ before an xpath like: "@[contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]/ancestor::li"

But there is no result too.
I should find element with whole text. Because i don't know what will be in span and what will be in div. I don't understand why element.Text = "text1\r\ntext2". But xpath "[contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]" doesnt't work.
Do you have any suggestions or comments? I'll be glad to see that
Thank you

Comment: Which text do you want from <li> ?

Comment: whole text "text1\r\ntext2"

Comment: But you have the div and span with text1 and text2 respectively in the same li element - therefore you cannot use that.  I presume you want li as the result of selection?

Comment: That is what you get as mentioned in your question. So you don't want \r\n ?

Comment: I should find element with whole text. Because i don't know what will be in span and what will be in div. I don't understand why element.Text = "text1\r\ntext2". But xpath "[contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]" doesnt't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use normalize-space, i guess it will fit your case too:

```
//*[normalize-space(text()='text1 text2')]/ancestor::li
```

Comment: This will return *all* `li` nodes with descendants as `normalize-space(text()='text1 text2')` will always return `true`

Comment: @EkaterinaShvyreva , no it's not :) You can pass **any** string to predicate like `//*[normalize-space(text()='John Rembo')]/ancestor::li ` and it will still return *the first `li` node*

Comment: Great , As @Andersson mentioned below : //li[normalize-space()='text1 text2'] will be more efficient

Comment: @Andersson, I didn't get you. How it could get li element doesn't contain the matching string ?!

Comment: Your predicate evaluates NOT the text of nodes, but simply that normalize-space from `'text1 text2'` returns `true`. I guess you mean `normalize-space(text())='text1 text2'`, but that will definitely not work. You can pass ANY non-empty string to `normalize-space` to make predicate `true`: `//*[normalize-space(@id='text1 text2')]/ancestor::li `, `//*[normalize-space('foo bar')]/ancestor::li ` and both will return `li`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `'John Rambo'` (not `'John Rembo'`)... I hope Silvester Stallone will never see that comment :))

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to perform a subquery for the li and test the children.  So something like the following would work for the above scenario:

```
//li[div[contains(text(),'text1')] and span[contains(text(), 'text2')]]
```

This will match all `li` who have a `div` element containing text1 and also a `span` element containing text2.

Comment: there is a whole text which I should find. And It can be changes ( i don't know which part would be in div and which part would be in span)